# Trying to get tag name but not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have two different pages, mouth.html and nose.html. I want to get a name from mouth.html. So when a user visit nose.html, it will print out the name of the place from mouth.html in nose.html. How can I do that in Javascript?

This is the code in mouth.html

```
 <h1 class="man" style="clear:both;">{{ moot.name }}</h1>
```

In nose.html, I tried this but it's not working

```
<script language="javascript">
   $("h1.man").load("mouth.html",function(data){
       var value=$(data).find("h1.man").attr("man")
   });

</script>
```

full codes in nose.html

```
 <head> 
   <script language="javascript">
       $.get( 'mouth.html', function( data ) {
        var mootName = $(data).text();
      // Do something with mootName here
      alert(mootName);
   });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="." method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}

    <div class="post-fed">
<p><label for="id_event_date">Event date:</label><input type="text" name="event_date" id="id_event_date" /><span class="helptext">E.g 2012-01-00.YYYY/MM/DD</span></p>
<p><label for="id_end_date">End date:</label><input type="text" name="end_date" id="id_end_date" /><span class="helptext">E.g. 2012-01-00.YYYY/MM/DD</span></p>
<p><label for="id_event_information">Event information:</label><textarea id="id_event_information" rows="10" cols="40" name="event_information"></textarea><span class="helptext"> E.g. eating etc</span></p>
<p><label for="id_full_name">Full name:</label><input id="id_full_name" type="text" name="full_name" maxlength="100" /></p>
<p><label for="id_e_mail">Email:</label></th><td><input id="id_e_mail" type="text" name="e_mail" maxlength="100" /></p>
<p><label for="id_phone_no">Phone no:</label></th><td><input id="id_phone_no" type="text" name="phone_no" maxlength="100" /></p>
<input type="submit"  class="put" value="Send"/> 

</form>  
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `var value = ...` does nothing visible. It just declares a variable, which is then discarded immediately because the function ends.

Comment: just to note, .attr("man") will get the value of the attribute man like <h1 man="value"></h1> which either way is not valid html.

try with .attr("class") to get the man value or .text() to get the inner text. don't know what value you want from the .attr(..) also see other answers for other solutions.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question.  You want to get the `{{ moot.name }}` from mouth.html, and then do what with it in nose.html?  log it? alert? modify a part of your page?

Answer (score 1):

You can load the element directly like this:

```
$('h1.man').load('mouth.html h1.man');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/load/

**Edit:**

As MichaelGeary pointed out, this also copies the element, which is not desirable (`<h1><h1></h1></h1>`). This would be better:

```
$.get('mouth.html', function(data) {
    var newText = $(data).find('h1.man').text();
    $('h1').text(newText);
});
```

Comment: Does it work even if, as Altinak noted, `h1.man` is the root node?

Comment: @JanDvorak the docs suggest it would, although it would seem that the OP has the load working anyway - it's the contents thereof he's looking at.

Comment: Yes, the `h1.man` functions as any other jQuery selector, according to the docs: 

“The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.”

Comment: Tried it like this <script language="javascript">
    $('h1.man').load('mouth.html h1.man');
    });
   </script> but it's not working, It's not showing an alert on the nose.html page about the name of the place.

Comment: Hmm... The doc has this example: `$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');` and it says "When this method executes, it retrieves the content of `ajax/test.html`, but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of `container`. *This element, along with its contents*, is inserted into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved document is discarded." [emphasis added] Doesn't this mean it will insert an extra copy of the `h1` element instead of grabbing the inner content only? The doc could certainly be more clear about this point.

Comment: Tried all this, but none is working. I'm a noob in javascript. kindly help me out.

Comment: @MichaelGeary it would seem that you would indeed get `<h1><h1>...</h1></h1>`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it will copy the elements with it: http://jsfiddle.net/FK3av/

Answer (score 1):

`.find` will only match *descendent* nodes, your `h1` is at the top of the tree.  You can use `.filter('h1.man')` to get the a matching top level node.

However, note that the callback will be invoked once for each top level element that was just inserted (with that node passed in `this`) so if the `<h1>` is really your top level node you can just use:

```
var value = $(this).attr(...);
```

This is much more efficient than calling `$(data)` using the HTML string because that `$(data)` just creates *another* in-memory copy of the downloaded content.

If I understand the docs correctly, you also need to call `.load()` on the *parent* of the existing `h1.man` element, since `.load()` will insert the loaded HTML *into* the specified element (replacing the existing contents) and not replace the originally specified element.

This also implies that this parent must *only* contain the `h1.man` element, suggesting that what you need is HTML thus:

```
<div id="h1_man_cont"><h1 class="man"> ... </h1></div>
```

and JS:

```
$('#h1_cont_man').load('mouth.html', function(data) {
    var value = $(this).attr(...);
});
```

Comment: What makes you think `h1` is the root?

Comment: @JanDvorak because that's what the OP says - _"this is the code in mouth.html"_

Comment: oh. Still kinda surprising that this is the _entire_ content.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the variety of answers and comments here, we're all a little confused about exactly what you're trying to do. So let me split it into two separate problems and we can look at each of those separately.

The first problem is a little more clear. You want to get the contents of `mouth.html` and grab some data out of it. `mouth.html` is a file generated from this Django template:

```
<h1 class="man" style="clear:both;">{{ moot.name }}</h1>
```

That's the entire template; there's no `<html>` or `<body>` or anything else.

So, for example, if your Python variable `moot.name` is "Mike", the entire content of `mouth.html` will be:

```
<h1 class="man" style="clear:both;">Mike</h1>
```

Now we want to load this file and grab "Mike" (or whatever) from it. We can do that like this:

```
$.get( 'mouth.html', function( data ) {
    var mootName = $(data).text();
    // Do something with mootName here
});
```

How this works: `$(data)` gives you the entire `<h1>` tag as a jQuery object, and then `.text()` grabs the inner text content from it.

Now for the next part, what to do with that name? You'd have to figure that out, or describe in more detail what you want to do, because that part isn't clear yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to display the name on nose.html page. Like, It will display 'You are about to book LAV GARDEN' at the top of the booking form, so when user book the GARDEN, it will save the bookings and the name of the place they booked. Hope you get my point? or should I illustrate it in Microsoft word and send the file to you?

Comment: OK, I think I follow you now. Unfortunately, that's a much more detailed and general kind of support than I could offer here. The best I can say is where my answer says "Do something with mootName here", that is where you will need to write some code to insert the value of `mootName` into your DOM where you need it. I don't know how the HTML on your booking page is structured, so I can't suggest anything beyond that. If you can show us what your HTML looks like, I could probably give a more specific suggestion, but I can't build that HTML page for you. (Sorry!)

Comment: OK, you placed the `$.get()` call in the `<head>` so it is executed before the document body is loaded. Is that what you want? When do you want this `$.get()` to happen? Like this, when the page is first loaded? Or after the DOM is ready? Or in responce to some user action? And what do you want to do with `mootName` after its value comes back from that call?

Comment: When a user click on "book" button which is the link to nose.html, when the page load, the mootName should display a text telling the user the name of the place he or she wants to book. E.g. "You are about to book Lav Garden" and below the text, there are forms to fill, so when user fill the form, the name of the place and the data the user input in the form should be saved. that's all I want to do. hope you get my point?

Comment: So write the code to do that, and then show us your code and tell us what is working and what isn't. I can't do that for you. I don't see a book button in your code. I don't know what it means to "display a text". I don't know what form fields to fill in. You really have to take a stab at this yourself, otherwise all I can do is keep asking you questions, and that will get tiresome fairly quickly.